# Asp.Net MVC + R# markup editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, coding-style, resharper

Editing of markup in MVC with Resharper makes me crazy! While I typing scriptlets (<% %>) It throws words and symbols, makes "magic" line breaks and tabs...
Is anybody solve this problem? In addition, do you know any coding guidelines or best practices of writing code in markup in MVC?

Comment: This should work. It does for me. What's your setup? VS version, R# version, project type, file type, etc? What view syntax?

Comment: VS 2010, R# 5, MVC 2, *.aspx. Foreach, for example. Complex lambda expressions. Or just try to create MVC Contrib Grid...  X_X

Comment: This is a good question, hopefully it'll get more upvotes than just mine. I generally don't have a problem, but at least one of my co-workers was befuddled by the autocomplete stuff. It can be quirky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit undo or cntrl-z to undo Resharper's auto formatting.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  This at the very least solves the magic line breaks and tabs problem.

Comment: jfar, it is no my downvote. Thanks for solution, I'll up you, if no another better idea appear.

Comment: Upvoted because that is the only way I've seen to fix this short of disabling lots of useful features . . .

Answer (score 1):

This is everything I know about Resharper Completion behavior: in Visual Studio in the menu bar, go to ReSharper >> Options... >> Environment >> IntelliSense >> Completion Behavior. Tweak as needed.